# control itunes with headphones push to talk button

Tags: windows-7, itunes, headphones

As you're probably aware, there is the possibility on an ipod to skip to the next/previous song or pause/play a song with the button available on some headphones. So now i was wondering whether the same would work with itunes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, the short answer is no. On a Macbook however, this should be supported out of the box.

From an old site that is no longer accessible:

> To launch iTunes, press the button once.
>
> To play/pause, press the button once.
>
> To skip to the next track, press the button twice.   To go back to the
>   previous track, press the button three times.

Comment: What's the long answer for Windows?

Comment: The long answer is that if your specific computer supports headset controlling, you might be able to get it to work out of the box. And if not, you might make a tool for registering the events and pass them on as actions.

Comment: I tried with AutoHotkey, nothing happened. I guess the events have to be captured using another method, or more probably, the kernel ignores them. I would be happy to know the answer though.